# Difference between antMatcher and mvcMatcher

Tags: spring, spring-security

What is difference of `HttpSecurity`'s `antMatcher()` and `mvcMatcher()` functions?

Could anyone explain when to use them ?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

As this methods' signatures clearly say is also stated in the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html) -

> `antMatcher(String antPattern)` - Allows configuring the `HttpSecurity` to only be invoked when matching the provided ant pattern.
>
> `mvcMatcher(String mvcPattern)` - Allows configuring the `HttpSecurity` to only be invoked when matching the provided Spring MVC pattern.

Generally `mvcMatcher` is more secure than an `antMatcher`. As an example:

- **`antMatchers("/secured")`** matches only *the exact* `/secured` URL
- **`mvcMatchers("/secured")`** matches `/secured` as well as `/secured/`, `/secured.html`, `/secured.xyz`

and therefore is more general and can also handle some possible configuration mistakes.

`mvcMatcher` uses the same rules that Spring MVC uses for matching (when using `@RequestMapping` annotation).

> If the current request will not be processed by Spring MVC, a reasonable default using the pattern as a ant pattern will be used. [Source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.RequestMatcherConfigurer.html)

It may be added that `mvcMatchers` API (since 4.1.1) is *newer* than the `antMatchers` API (since 3.1).

Comment: Spring Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authorization-filtersecurityinterceptor

Comment: > mvcMatcher is more secure than antMatcher

> shows example, that mvcMatcher can match more things than what you actually write down.

I don't know about you, but this is clearly the opposite

Comment: It sounds it's quite opposite, but mvcMatchers are more secure because they can match more... for example, imagine example: `.mvcMatchers("/employee").hasRole("xyz").anyRequest().aunthenticated() ... permitAll()`...  if you want to get to employee resource and type `/employee/` or `/employee.html`, the mvcMatcher will match your request and filter through authentication ... antMatcher would not catch `/employee/` case and would not filter request through auth and can exploit resource ... DispatcherServlet will server request .. this is just a security filtering ...

Comment: I would also have a look at this video: https://youtu.be/WsH8qn8hjgE
It does a great job demonstrating how a single slash can break antMatchers, whereas mvcMatchers is able to catch it.

Answer (score 10):

`AntMatcher()` is an implementation for Ant-style path patterns. Part of this mapping code has been kindly borrowed from Apache Ant.

`MvcMatcher()` uses Spring MVC's `HandlerMappingIntrospector` to match the path and extract variables.

So they both implement `RequestMatcher` interface, but use different expression languages under the hood.

Answer (score 5):

```
antMatcher("/users/**") matches any path starting with /users
antMatchers("/users") matches only the exact /users URL
mvcMatchers("/users") matches /users, /users/, /users.html

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/users/movie/**") // matches any path starting with /users/movie
  .hasRole("ADMIN") ...
  }
}
```