# SecurityFilterChain fails to instantiate after spring boot migration from 3.0.8 to 3.0.9

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

In my spring boot project I've got the following definition of a SecurityFilterChain:

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http

    // public routes
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers("/", "/favicon.ico", "/v3/api-docs*")
    .permitAll()
    .and()

    // enable security for the log-view
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers("/log")
    .hasAnyRole(ROLE_LOGVIEWER)
    .and()

    // enable security for the health check
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers("/manage/health")
    .hasAnyRole(ROLE_HEALTH)
    .and()

    // enable basic-auth and ROLE_USER for all other routes
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .hasAnyRole(ROLE_USER)
    .and()
    .httpBasic();

  return http.build();
}
```

It's tested in several mockup tests and runs as expected in the production environment.

But after the migration from spring-boot 3.0.8 to 3.0.9, I've got the following error:

```
Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).
```

I tried to use a more specific requst matcher, but without success.

Any hints for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user2959589 answer shows me the right way, thanks!

```
http
    // public routes
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/"))
    .permitAll()
    .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/favicon.ico"))
    .permitAll()
    .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/v3/api-docs*"))
    .permitAll()
    .and()

    // enable security for the log-view
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/log"))
    .hasAnyRole(ROLE_LOGVIEWER)
    .and()

    // enable security for the health check
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/manage/health"))
    .hasAnyRole(ROLE_HEALTH)
    .and()

    // enable basic-auth and ROLE_USER for all other routes
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .hasAnyRole(ROLE_USER)
    .and()
    .httpBasic();
```

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same exception in a very basic configuration with Spring Security 6.1.2. I solved it with:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.
            authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> {
                    requests.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/"), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/style.css")).permitAll();
                    requests.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/secure/**")).hasAuthority("MyAuthority");
            }).
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way do to it but it does seem to work. Within Spring Security 6, `AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry` doesn't have a `.antMatchers()` method anymore. Again, not really sure if this is the best way and not completely sure why I would want an ant matcher vs an MVC endpoint matcher.

Comment: There is a GitHub issue already created. So for more info, check: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/13568

Comment: @Jake_3H : So what is the right answer on this within 3.1.2? Do we use AntPathMatcher or MvcRequestMatcher? This is very important because it's the security configuration, and I want to make sure I'm protecting the resources I think I'm protecting.

Comment: That mostly depends on the patterns u use and their use-case. I would say AntPathMatcher is the way to go if u have exactly specific route(s), that u want to configure (for example in our app, we require auth for everything but /health route, so I went with AntPathMatcher). Here is a nice link explaining their difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536292/difference-between-antmatcher-and-mvcmatcherv