Springboot 3.3.2 spring security 6 - broken authentication after migration from springboot 2.7.12
We are migrating Spring Boot 2.7.12 project to Springboot 3.3.2. We are struggling to configure the spring security after upgrade as its not working as expected. The project structure is as follows. The acme-parent-library is the maven project which is the serves as parent for all the service projects. spring-boot-dependencies pom added in the parent project parent project in pom.

Common security config is defined in this parent project as follows. (this is applicable for all services)
@Configuration
@Order(50)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class AcmeSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
        http
                .requestMatchers()
                .mvcMatchers("api/v1/**", "api/v2/**", "api/v3/**", "/actuator/health")
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
    }
    
    //Filters
}

Another security configuration present in service-1 : additional configuration for the service-1 which is ordered higher than the parent security configuration
@Configuration
@Order(40)
public class Service1Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
        http
                    .requestMatchers()
                    .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "ap1/v1/signup")
                    .and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("ap1/v1/signup")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and().csrf().disable();
    
        http
                    .requestMatchers()
                    .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "api/v1/apptest/**")
                    .and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("api/v1/apptest/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and().csrf().disable();

}

After the migration, the parent configuration is updated as follows
@Configuration
@Order(50)
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class AcmeSecurityConfig {   
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.exceptionHandling(handling -> handling.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)));
            
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("health")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("api/v1/**", "api/v2/**", "api/v3/**",).authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated());
    
        return http.build();
    }
}

And finally the configuration in service-1 is updated as follows
@Configuration
@Order(40)
public class Service1Config {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "ap1/v1/signup").authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers("ap1/v1/signup").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "api/v1/apptest/**").authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers("api/v1/apptest/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
        return http.build();
    }
}

Everything works fine with this config on Springboot 2.7.12 with spring-security 5.7.12. Now we have Springboot 3.3.2 with Spring security 6.3.1 but the security rules are now broken. We have the test cases that are all passing in old version and but after migration the tests are failing with 401/403s. Are the method we used in spring security 6 are correct? Please help to have the same configuration as before. Also it looks like the configuration defined in service1 not taken into account. Is it not possible to have the security config in two places in spring security 6?

api/v1/** here you are saying that everything below v1 should be authenticated. But then ap1/v1/signup here you are saying that this should be permitted. Order does not mean that one rule overrides a different rule. Order just means in which order a rule should be applied. Hence the name ORDER. so in that case, the first rule will let a request to ap1/v1/signup through, but will get caught in the second filterchain. you should have separate chains for different parts

Also you have really strange rules you are mixing mvcMatchers with antMatchers for the same endpoint i recommend you learn the difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536292/difference-between-antmatcher-and-mvcmatcher

Ensure that the @Order annotation on Service1Config is set to a lower value (e.g., 30) to make it have a higher priority than the AcmeSecurityConfig.

Read the news/upgrade guides... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-6.x

@Toerktumlare The mix of mvcMatchers (only targeting a specific HTTP method) and the antMatchers are part of the existing configuration . I understand that these methods are no-longer available in new version and that is why I have used requestMatchers.

@amirrad We have the order=40 in service and order=50 in the common config. Since we have SecurityFilterChain beans as part of Spring security 6, I also tried putting Order on top of the  beans that also not working.

Is it possible to have different configuration classes for spring security 6? Why I am asking this is we have only the @Configuration annotation on top of the service config but all security related annotations present only in parent class

I'm also having the same issue with Spring Security 6.3.1. It feels very broken. Apparently, disabling CSRF doesn't work. I've tried with a very simple application and it still requires CSRF for requests capable of changing data (e.g. POST,PUT, etc) regardless of the configuration and attempts to disabled it completely or for some URLs. Currently, my OAUTH2 clients are broken because they can't POST to the endpoint.
Both of these configurations have no effect on my sample application.
.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
.csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/post/**"))
